# How do I create a multi-tenant view structure in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I am constructing a demo project where multiple tenants will have their own collection of views.  Additionally a default view collection will be available if the tenant does not have a specialized view. I have seen multiple tutorials on doing the code side with multi-tenant where each has their own Database.  But the view side seems to be lacking.

In psuedo code:

```
Get Me the User information view
Get tentantname from current context
Check /views/{tentantname}/userinfo/index.cshtml
if found return /views/{tentantname}/userinfo/index.cshtml
else return /views/base/userinfo/index.html
```

I am unsure where to handle this code?  (Create a base controller that overrides the call to view maybe)
Should I create my own version of the RazorViewEngine?
Is this handled in a route config? (This is more controller routing then where to look for a view)
What method needs to be overridden?

I have found tutorials on changing the base directory of all views but I am looking to handle the look up of each view on a case by case basis.  Leveraging a value in the current context of the running request.

EDIT in reference to first answer.

The changes made to the RazorViewEngine removed many of the overridable methods used in the example.  The same author added an update http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/custom-viewengine-aspnet5-mvc6 
But this version does not go into the view location check and rewriting.  I think the answer is in one of the parameters passed into the constructor.  I think if could override on of them I could accomplish my task.  Here is the RazorViewEngine from the meta data:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Default implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.IRazorViewEngine.
//
// Remarks:
//     For ViewResults returned from controllers, views should be located in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.ViewLocationFormats
//     by default. For the controllers in an area, views should exist in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.AreaViewLocationFormats.
public class RazorViewEngine : IRazorViewEngine, IViewEngine
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
    //     class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   pageFactory:
    //     The page factory used for creating Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage instances.
    public RazorViewEngine(IRazorPageFactory pageFactory, IRazorViewFactory viewFactory, IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions> optionsAccessor, IViewLocationCache viewLocationCache);

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the locations where this instance of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
    //     will search for views within an area.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The locations of the views returned from controllers that belong to an area.
    //     Locations are composite format strings (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx),
    //     which contains following indexes: {0} - Action Name {1} - Controller Name {2}
    //     - Area name The values for these locations are case-sensitive on case-senstive
    //     file systems. For example, the view for the Test action of HomeController should
    //     be located at /Views/Home/Test.cshtml. Locations such as /views/home/test.cshtml
    //     would not be discovered
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> AreaViewLocationFormats { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the locations where this instance of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine
    //     will search for views.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The locations of the views returned from controllers that do not belong to an
    //     area. Locations are composite format strings (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx),
    //     which contains following indexes: {0} - Action Name {1} - Controller Name The
    //     values for these locations are case-sensitive on case-senstive file systems.
    //     For example, the view for the Test action of HomeController should be located
    //     at /Views/Home/Test.cshtml. Locations such as /views/home/test.cshtml would not
    //     be discovered
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> ViewLocationFormats { get; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the case-normalized route value for the specified route key.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   context:
    //     The Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionContext.
    //
    //   key:
    //     The route key to lookup.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The value corresponding to the key.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The casing of a route value in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionContext.RouteData is
    //     determined by the client. This making constructing paths for view locations in
    //     a case sensitive file system unreliable. Using the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions.ActionDescriptor.RouteValueDefaults
    //     for attribute routes and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions.ActionDescriptor.RouteConstraints
    //     for traditional routes to get route values produces consistently cased results.
    public static string GetNormalizedRouteValue(ActionContext context, string key);
    //
    public RazorPageResult FindPage(ActionContext context, string pageName);
    //
    public ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ActionContext context, string partialViewName);
    //
    public ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName);
}
```

If you notice only one two properies are virtual.  I think one of the constructor parameters could be overwritten so that when FindView() is called something could be done.  I don't know at this point and I can not find an example or tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would create your own CustomViewEngine that inherits from `RazorViewEngine`. In there, you would read the tenantname from the context and then specify the paths to look in.

Here is a [blog post describing creating your own ViewEngine](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location).

Update: you should also check [View Location Expander](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-location-expander-aspnet5-mvc6)

Comment: I looked at that tutorial but the RazorViewEngine class changed significantly in MVC 5.  Particularly the only virtual propertoes are the AreaViewLocationFormats and ViewLocationFormats..  The FindView is not virtual.  I believe one of the parameters in the constructor could be the answer but I am having trouble finding information on them.  (IRazorViewFactory may be the key).

Comment: @dan, have you checkec view location expender? http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-location-expander-aspnet5-mvc6

Comment: @user960567 That is the answer!  Put that up and I will give you credit.  Its a shame Imran does not link to that in his other two solutions.  I knew this was not that complicated.

Comment: @Dan feel free to mark the above as answer. Updated it.